# What is the probablity of getting balls form urn?

Tags: probability

An urn contains 25 balls numbered 1 to 25. Suppose an odd number is considered a 'success' . Two balls are drawn from the urn with replacement.

1) Find the probablity of getting two successes.

2) Find the probablity of getting exactly one success

3) Find the probability of getting at least one success.

4) Find the probability of getting no success.

Now i explains my approach for the first question so that you get an idea where i am wrong.

Urn has 13 balls with odd numbers and 12 balls with even numbers. So for the first question if i want two successes the probability should be 13/25 *  12/25 = 156/625

But i am not getting the right answer. Pleas solve.

Comment: When you take one ball out of the urn, total number of balls is 24, so probability is: $\dfrac{12}{25}\cdot \dfrac{12}{24}$.

Comment: @malimish it is a question of replacement

Comment: Sry, probability is $\dfrac{13}{25}\cdot \dfrac{13}{25}$. If it was without replacement, then it would be $\dfrac{13}{25}\cdot \dfrac{12}{24}$, so first comment has an error anyway.

Comment: @malimish my question is in replacemnet we replace a particular thing with other thing so total ball will be 25 after replacement thats i understand but how the success will be 13 again...is not it should be 12 because we have taken out a success earlier..now it should left 12 (13-1)

Comment: but replacement means that if you take ball with number 9, before second draw we put the ball with number 9 back to urn, so we are back at the start with 13/25 percent of success.

Answer (score 1):

*with replacement* means you're returning the ball to the urn. So

$(1)$ $\frac{13}{25} \times \frac{13}{25}$

$(2)$ $\big(\frac{13}{25} \times \frac{12}{25}\big) + \big(\frac{12}{25} \times \frac{13}{25}\big)$

$(3)$ Sum of the above quantities: $\big(\frac{13}{25} \times \frac{13}{25}\big) + \big(\frac{13}{25} \times \frac{12}{25}\big) + \big(\frac{12}{25} \times \frac{13}{25}\big)$

$(4)$ $\big(\frac{12}{25} \times \frac{12}{25}\big)$

Note that the *number* on the ball is only important up to whether it is *odd* or *even*. The exact number doesn't matter. So you can visualize the problem more clearly if you consider the urn having $13$ *red* balls and $12$ *blue* balls, picking a *red* ball meaning *success*, and a *blue* ball meaning *failure*.

Comment: my question is in replacemnet we replace a particular thing with other thing so total ball will be 25 after replacement thats i understand but how the success will be 13 again...is not it should be 12 because we have taken out a success earlier..now it should left 12 (13-1) –

Comment: First of all, *without replacement* is a *technical word* in *combinatorics* and *statistics*, you cannot assign literal (or arbitrary) meaning to it. When you're picking a ball from the urn, it's called a *trial*. The ball maybe numbered *odd* or *even*. Then you are *not* replacing it by *something else*. By *replacing* we mean that the *same* ball is returned to the urn. So before performing the next *trial*, the same initial setup with the *same* 25 balls are arranged. In a *with replacement* process, each trial has identical initial setup and is independent of the result of other trials.

Answer (score 0):

We use **Binomial Distribution** here. The formula that finds the probabilities for the binomial distribution for probability of success $p$, fixed number of trials $n$, and $k$ successes is as follows: $$\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$ Here $p$ stands for the probability of a correct answer and obviously $(1-p)$ for that of a wrong answer. Let $X$ denote the variable to represent the number of odd numbers that we get. Obviously, we have $p=\frac{13}{25}$ since there are $13$ odd numbers. Using this,

$(1)$ $n =2, k=2, p=\frac{13}{25}$ So our answer is $\binom{2}{2}(13/25)^2(12/25)^0$.
$(2)$ $n =2, k=1$.
$(3)$ $P_{\text{req}} = P(X=1) + P(X=2)$.
$(4)$ $P_{\text{req}} = P(X=0)$ where $n=2, k=0$.   Hope it helps.